# Replace Value in column based on value in given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in the data frame which allowed only values present in a defined list.

E.g.: Given a list l1 = [1,2,5,6], I need to replace every value with "0" if value in column is not present in the list

| column | **Expected column** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | **0** |
| 4 | **0** |
| 3 | **0** |
| 6 | 6 |

I have tried using loc

```
df.loc[~l1, 0, df.column]
```

But this says **TypeError**. What is the efficient way in python to replace the value ?

Comment: Use `m = ~df['column'].isin(l1)
df.loc[m, 'column'] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[~df['column'].isin(l1), 'Expected column'] = 0
```