# Replacing several different values in Pandas Column with 'Other'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop, replace

I have a data frame of about 100 rows all with different values that looks something like the following:

Data frame 1:

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Celery |
| 1 | Beetroot |
| 2 | Pineapple |

I also have another data frame that looks something like this:

Data frame 2:

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple |
| 1 | Carrot |
| 2 | Pineapple |
| 3 | Celery |
| 4 | Beetroot |

And want to modify all the values in Data frame 1 to 'Other' In data frame 2 like:

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple |
| 1 | Carrot |
| 2 | Other |
| 3 | Other |
| 4 | Other |

I could do this individually for every value but there are too many, and am a bit stuck on how to turn this into a loop:

## Modifying beetroot to 'Other'

data_frame2 = data_frame2.replace([Beetroot], 'Other')

Comment: Use: `df2.loc[df2['Values'].isin(df1['Values']), 'Values'] = 'Other'`

Comment: @mozway - Can you change dupe because no match?

Comment: @jezrael sure, but you should know (e.g., [you closed this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448007/replace-value-in-column-based-on-value-in-given-list))